# How is phpMyAdmin symbolic link configured

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

I've setup phpMyAdmin in the `/var/www/html` folder using symbolic links to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` using `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/* /var/www/html/`

So when I go to the URL I get phpMyAdmin, but when I go to http://URL/phpmyadmin the phpMyAdmin page is still there, this isn't a problem since it doesnt cause any errors, but it bothered me a bit so I'm wondering how it is linked.

I thought it would either be because:

1. There is a symbolic link
2. phpMyAdmin is actually located there
3. It is linked in one of the Apache2 files

But there appear to be no symbolic links, the phpMyAdmin folder isn't there and I check the apache2 config files but there is not a single mention of phpMyAdmin. So how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled across the answer, it's a conf file located inside the `/etc/apache2/conf-available`. I should've researched it more before I asked the question here, I thought I had hid a dead end.